# Is it good idea to clean DB for testing after each test in frontend?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, end-to-end

When testing frontend, i am calling backend API to clean DB after each test. The reason for that is to make every test independent from each other.

Shortly after I started doing so, I faced issues with some API calls being made after cleaning the DB. It is expected behavior since there might be some async tasks still running from previous tests. So now I am thinking "maybe I made a bad decision trying to clean DB after each test?"

What are the better ways to test frontend avoiding mocks as much as possible?

Previously I used to mock API calls. However, it requires you to keep API mocks up to date which became burden to me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you're cleaning the DB after each test run and not waiting until the entire test suite has been executed? Are you re-using the same/identical test data across tests?

Comment: @TestPete Some tests might fill up DB with unique test data. I use one test suite for one web page.

Comment: Can you share an example of what such a web page might be? Is it a products page, a user profile or ..?
And can you list a couple of tests you've run against it, including a few words on the test data used. 

As you might sense, I would investigate it the test data itself may ensure independent tests, to avoid cleaning the DB between tests (and avoid mocks).